# AngularJS: Passing object parameter from view to a controller function

Tags: jquery, angularjs, model-view-controller

I have an Html page in an angularjs based application, 
I want to extract the data from the page(for example, from-date and to-date) and then pass this data into the controller.
I want to pass it within a single object.

eg:

```
<button ng-click="myControllerFunc(myObject)" />
```

How to create this myobject and pass it to the myControlerFunc?

Comment: is from-date and to-date in scope?

Comment: from date and to-date are not in scope, they are just textbox values

Comment: you can put them in scope by assigning scope variables to ng-model of the respective textboxes

Answer (score 2):

in case you are using ng-repeat on an object u could directly send in your object with the function call, eg:-

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
 <button data-ng-click="callFunction(item)">call my object</button>
</div>
```

....

in your controller you can read it in your function

```
$scope.callFunction = function(item){
     console.log(item);
};
```

Hence you get the complete data . Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If the data is in scope and then you want to populate myObject on the click of the button, you can do something like this in the controller:

```
$scope.myControllerFunc =function(myObject) {
     myObject.fromDate = $scope.fromDate;
     myObject.toDate = $scope.toDate;
}
```

If from an html element you want the data then you can make use of angular.element and do something like this:

```
$scope.myControllerFunc =function(myObject) {
     var fromDate = angular.element( document.querySelector( '#fromDate' ) );
     var toDate= angular.element( document.querySelector( '#toDate' ) );
     myObject.fromDate = fromDate.val();
     myObject.toDate = toDate.val();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define the object (in your example, we're talking about `myObject`) ahead of time in your controller on the `$scope` object, and simply use [`ng-model`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) to bind the fields to the properties on the object. You do not have to define the object ahead of time, though. `ngModel` will create the object for you when binding, if it can.

```
  <form name="frm" ng-submit="myControllerFunc(myObject)">
    From date:
    <input type="date" ng-model="myObject.fromDate" />
    <br />To date:
    <input type="date" ng-model="myObject.toDate" />
    <br />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    <small>Check console log for value upon submit</small>
  </form>
```

For the function, define it on the `$scope` object in your controller. In this example, passing in the object is superfluous as you can just reference it on `$scope` rather than an argument, but you may have your reasons.

```
$scope.myControllerFunc = function(obj) {
    console.log(obj); // do whatever you want with obj
};
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/ssGWnKg8Q1zzphRlPwdJ?p=preview).

For the sake of completeness, here's the body of the controller if you define things ahead of time.

```
$scope.myObject = { fromDate: null, toDate: null };

$scope.myControllerFunc = function() {
    console.log($scope.myObject); // do whatever you want with obj
};
```

The view would not be any different except you can remove the parameter from `ng-submit`:

```
<form name="frm" ng-submit="myControllerFunc()">
```

Mix and match according to your needs.

Also, you do not have to use `ng-submit` to call the function as shown in my examples (I didn't see your edit that included this detail). You can just call `myControllerFunc` from your button `ng-click` in the same way I've used it in `ng-submit`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a slight misunderstanding of how angular works. Your page would look like this with your to and from date inside the controller like below.

```
<div data-ng-controller="searchBar" data-ng-init="id='g3_v1'" class="widget">
    <form data-ng-submit="formSubmit()">
        From date: <input data-ng-model="fromDate" type="text" ><br/>
        To   date: <input data-ng-model="toDate" type="text" ><br/>
        <button ng-click="formSubmit()" />
    </form>
</div>
```

The controller code as following:

```
$scope.formSubmit = function() {
    var data = {"toDate":$scope.toDate, 
                "fromDate": $scope.fromDate};
    $http({
        url: "json/search", 
        method: "GET",
        params: data
     }).then(
         function(resp)
         {
             //success callback
         },
         function(error)
         {
             //failure callback
     });
};
```

In case the toDate and fromDate are out of your control, you can use service to set the same variables inside a controller.